# Quatrz Scalability - fails with large number of triggers per second

Tags: quartz-scheduler

we are not able to fire more than 30 triggers per second.

Its clustered instance with 16GB RAM machine. (two quartz instances)

Quartz starts to delay or hang after 30 triggers per second.

> org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 100
>   org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount=100
>   org.quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime=15000

we need to go up to atleast 100 triggers per second.

we are using Postgres as database.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the [best practices](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/best-practices) of using Quartz.

At above link, go through this header : "Ensure Adequate Datasource Connection Size" and check if something fruitful is there. :-)

Comment: Yes, we have followed this link.